# Gallery syntax error

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, syntax-error, blueimp

I keep getting this error on chrome while trying to make the blueimp gallery work and I cannot figure out where the issue is, or how to fix it. I'm nearly positive I did something simple before and fixed it but forgot to save the changes and I don't know what I did. The error is coming from line 2 of the code below. And I have imported the blueimp after jquery.

> Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Code :

```
$(document).ready(function()
  document.getElementById('links').onclick = function (event) {
    event = event || window.event;
    var target = event.target || event.srcElement,
        link = target.src ? target.parentNode : target,
        options = {
            index: link,
            event: event
        },
        links = this.getElementsByTagName('a');
    blueimp.Gallery(links, options);
 }
);
```

Comment: Why aren't you using jQuery event handlers?

Comment: You forgot `{` after `$(document).ready(function()`.

Comment: @SLaks Because I have never heard of them before. Learning this by myself so there's  a lot of googling and guessing going on.

Comment: @Regent that just gives me an unclosed bracket and it doesn't work if I add it to the end

Comment: Yes, I didn't notice that you also forgot `}` before `);` in last line.

Comment: Function bodies always have to be within `{...}`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: Thanks guys, I can move on to my next error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't realise I was missing brackets. Added }); to the end of it and it worked.